# Email Notification to users after provisioning new OneDrive for Business in Office 365

Tags: email, office365, onedrive

I want to send email notification to users after provisioning their new OneDrive for Business in Office 365. Is there any OOTB configuration in Office 365 to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Microsoft, there is no way we can configure email so that users can get email once they provision their OneDrive for Business.